# Running a method just once using python Unittest or pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, python-unittest

I am on a website where you login, then search for course, click on course and then it lands on the Credit card page, since its just one course and is common and I am just trying to run DDT on CC section and not search section this is what I did
1.Login is through conftest in conftest.py

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="class")
def oneTimeSetUp(request, browser):
    print("Running one time setUp")
    wdf = WebDriverFactory(browser)
    driver = wdf.getWebDriverInstance()
    lp = LoginPage(driver)
    lp.login("test@fake.com", "xxyyzz")
```

2.On the test page this is how my code looks like

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp","setUp")
@ddt
class SendformTest(unittest.TestCase):


    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
        self.sf = SendForms(self.driver)
        self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)


    def setUp(self):  ############ I want this method to run just once after login, this method searches for course and then clicks and land on cc page
        self.sf.navigateToCCForms("img")


    '
    @pytest.mark.run(order = 1)
    @data(*getCSVData("testRegular.csv"))
    @unpack
    def test_cc_Form(self,ccNum, ccExp, ccCVV):
        result = self.sf.verifyOnCCforms() 
        self.ts.mark(result,"On Send Form Page")
        self.sf.ccdetails(ccNum, ccExp, ccCVV)
        result1 = self.sf.sentSuccessMsg()
        self.ts.markFinal("test_sending_Form", result1, "this is test")
```

Right now this runs once fine and then just sits there, it wont enter data multiple times on the CC page.
Thank you

Comment: If you want it to run after the login, why not just put that code at the end of that method? Or in a tearDown rather than the setUp.

Comment: I am using login class its method in other test case and navigation isn't common in those test cases so cant add it to end of the method.
I also figured out setUp is not the right method to use in here because Setup runs before and after the test_cc_form and that is the reason why it runs fine once and then just stays there.
i am looking for some other unittest method that I can use to run once before the test_cc_form method